# I'm trying to migrate database through rails and its throwing following an error table is existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run command '`rails db:migrate`' to **migrate database** through *rails* and its throwing following an error :

> StandardError: Table "admin_user" already exists: RENAME TABLE 'users' TO 'admin_users'

Code is :

```
    class ChangeUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    rename_table("users","admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users","username",:string,:limit=>25,:after=>"email")
    change_column("admin_users","email",:string,:limit=>25)
    rename_column("admin_users","password","hashed_password")
    add_index("admin_users","username")
  end

  def down
     remove_index("admin_users","username")
     rename_column("admin_users","hashed_password","password")
     change_column("admin_users","email",:string,:default=> '',:null =>false)
     remove_column("admin_users","username")
     rename_table("admin_users","users")
   end
end
```

Schema.rb file here :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_06_08_070345) do

  create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name", limit: 25
    t.string "last_name", limit: 25
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.string "password", limit: 8
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: What is the output of `rails db:migrate:status`?

Comment: @AkashPinnaka here is status : 

Do Nothing = UP  |  Create users = UP  |  Change users = Down

Comment: Can you update your question with **db/schema.rb**?

Comment: Ok i updated with schema.rb file and code